# gl-react-expo shader with external image texture input

Tags: reactjs, react-native, opengl, shader, expo

I'm trying to use gl-react-expo shaders to apply some effects on some images in an Expo project. The images are from an external url (like https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyvNE.jpg).

I can make simple shaders that don't use a texture input, and it works perfectly. But I am not finding the correct way to pass the image to the shader. I'm trying to implement the DiamondCrop example from this site (http://greweb.me/2016/06/glreactconf/) and all the other simple examples that I found that passes an image to the shader. But none of them work.

This is my shader definition:

```
import React from "react";
import { Shaders, Node, GLSL } from "gl-react";

const frags = {
    diamond: GLSL`
    precision highp float;
    varying vec2 uv;
    uniform sampler2D t;
    void main () {
      gl_FragColor = mix(
        texture2D(t, uv),
        vec4(0.0),
        step(0.5, abs(uv.x - 0.5) + abs(uv.y - 0.5))
      );
    }`
}



const shaders = Shaders.create({
  DiamondCrop: {
    frag: frags.image
  }
});

const DiamondCrop = ({ children: t }) => (
  <Node
    shader={shaders.DiamondCrop}
    // uniformsOptions={{
    //     t: { interpolation: "nearest" },
    //   }}
    uniforms={ { t } }
  >
  </Node>
);

export { DiamondCrop }
```

I tried passing the image in the following ways:

```
// 1

<Surface style={{width: 200, height: 200}}>
    <DiamondCrop>
        {{uri:'https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyvNE.jpg'}}
    </DiamondCrop>
</Surface>


// 2

<Surface style={{width: 200, height: 200}}>
    <DiamondCrop>
        {{image:{uri:'https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyvNE.jpg'}}}
    </DiamondCrop>
</Surface>


// 3

<Surface style={{width: 200, height: 200}}>
    <DiamondCrop>
        https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyvNE.jpg
    </DiamondCrop>
</Surface>


// 4

<Surface style={{width: 200, height: 200}}>
    <DiamondCrop>
        {'https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyvNE.jpg'}
    </DiamondCrop>
</Surface>
```

And the errors I get are the following:

```
// 1 (on 'expo red screen of death')

undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expo2.default.FileSystem')


// 2 (Expo warning; nothing appears on the Surface region)

Node#1(DiamondCrop#2), uniform t: no loader found for value, Object {
  "image": Object {
    "uri": "https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyvNE.jpg",
  },
}, Object {
  "image": Object {
    "uri": "https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyvNE.jpg",
  },
}


// 3 (Expo warning; nothing appears on the Surface region)

Node#1(DiamondCrop#2), uniform t: no loader found for value, https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyvNE.jpg, https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyvNE.jpg


// 4 (Expo warning; nothing appears on the Surface region)

Node#1(DiamondCrop#2), uniform t: no loader found for value, https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyvNE.jpg, https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyvNE.jpg
```

Could anyone point me in the right directions to accomplish this task??

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I am using your #1 and it's supposed to be the correct one, I guess (according to [this](https://github.com/gre/gl-react/issues/121#issuecomment-421375049)). Couldn't figured out a solution yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is quite old, but I wanted to write an answer for those who may be into the gl related stuff with react-native and Expo.

**TL;DR** The reason this is happening is because the library gl-react-expo is outdated, it is doing `import Expo from "Expo"` which is deprecated(breaks the entire thing actually) in V33 of expo SDK.

I made a github repo that hosts the corrected libraries, you may want to use that. Here is the link [gl-expo-libraries](https://github.com/afrozopsy/gl-expo-libraries) Also, If you want to stick to original libraries then go to the node_modules folder, go to the gl-react-expo fodler and look for _expo2 variable in the files and change _expo2.default to _expo. It will do the trick.

Cheers :)

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer! I'm gonna try your solution as soon as I have some time, and then I'll let you know how it worked.